# Profile screen when tabs on top

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, profile

I am making an Android app. When the equivalent of this app on iOS is using bottom tabs, the recommended way to get it onto Android is to use a top tab bar like this:

[image]

---

So true to this, I have created this here:

[image]

---

However I need to make this a **profile screen** like for instance:

[image]

However I can't figure out how to do this. The tab bar is in the way.
Is there any recommendations on how you would do a **profile screen when there are top tabs?**

Comment: What happens when they press the back button on the profile screen?

Comment: @RobEarle In the profile screen that's a demo. But if that back button was in my tabbed navigator,  it would take them to the initial tab.

Answer (score 2):

The profile screen in the 3rd image is **one level deeper in the hierarchy** from your main page (I mean the page with tabs). So, when the user clicks on a button which is a link to the profile screen, the profile screen overlays over the main page. Clicking on the ' <- ' Back button would take the user back to the main page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kishan I think what I'm going to do is put make the part between the tab bar and title bar expand and be the profile image/info like this - http://ionicmaterial.com/assets/img/android/01_device.png??v=0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer, I think I'll make the part between the tab bar and title bar expand. This part will contain the profile background and info like this:

[image]

Comment: No.. 1. The profile page should contain details to be shown in the profile only, not the tab bar. 2. Tab bar should not shift its place if u are following material.

Comment: Thanks @Kishan may you please share a screenshot of what I should do? your solution above i think was telling me to create another screen?